# Cannot resolve symbol "R" Android Studio 1.2

Tags: android

Am tried opening my old project that I built in Eclipse, into Andorid Studio.

I have this import statement throughout my app, that used to work:

```
import com.btf271.fashionassistant.R;
```

Now it cannot resolve the R.

I have looked at many solutions for similar questions but the first thing to try is cleaning and syncing the gradle, and the ways they say to do that, must be for an older version of Android studio, and I have Android Studio 1.2, I cannot see how to do it.

EDIT: Or maybe I do not, Clicking about says Android Studio (Beta 0.8.9) - I updated Android Studio via "help" > "Check for update" and I think it only goes to the next version, not the newest - may try downloading Android Studio 1.2 instead.

I have rebuilt the project and restarted Android Studio and they did not work.

Any suggestions about that?

The answers to the duplicate do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need to import `R` anymore